# Ansible SSH as one user and Sudo as another

Tags: ssh, ansible, sudo, ansible-inventory, ansible-ad-hoc

I have some difficulties to adapt Ansible configuration to my environment.

My testing environment :

- PermitRootLogin no
- Only one user allowed to connect through SSH (foo, without any privileges)
- A user with sudo privileges (bar ALL=(ALL) ALL)

My ansible host inventory looks like this :

```
[servers]
server1 ansible_ssh_host=192.168.0.1 ansible_sudo=true ansible_ssh_user=foo ansible_sudo_user=bar
```

I have an SSH key for foo user.

When I try this ad hoc command (or any other) with bar password :

```
ansible server1 -m raw -a "echo test > /etc/testfile" --ask-sudo-pass
server1 | FAILED => Incorrect sudo password
```

Then if I do the same command with foo password :

```
ansible server1 -m raw -a "echo test > /etc/testfile" --ask-sudo-pass
Sorry, user foo is not allowed to execute '/bin/bash -c echo SUDO-SUCCESS-rlpfhamukjnsfyokqbjpbttviiuildif; echo test > /etc/testfile' as bar on server1.
```

So Ansible definitely use foo as sudo user and not bar as I specified. Is there a way to force the use of bar instead of foo? I really don't understand the sudo functionality on Ansible, even if I use the same user for everything (bar for SSH and bar password) ansible give returns me :

```
server1 | FAILED | rc=1 >>
echo test > /etc/testfile : Permission denied
```

When I'm logging as bar on my host and doing "sudo echo test > /etc/testfile" it ask me for bar password and does the command correctly. Where am I wrong with Ansible behavior ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think of it like this:

- `ansible_ssh_user` is the user to ssh to the host as
- `ansible_sudo_user` is the user to sudo on the host

In other words, using your users and commands as the example, the equivalent commands that ansible will run are:

`ssh foo@server1 sudo -u bar "echo test > testfile"`

Therefore the `foo` user's password needs to be provided, not the `bar` user. The `foo` user will need privileges to sudo as `bar`. Something like this in `sudoers`:

```
foo    ALL=(bar) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Now `foo` can run all commands as `bar` with no password.